# Remove iistart.htm?

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to rename (or even remove) iisstart.htm. I have tried the below but it is not doing anything. The result does not change anything:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.webServer/defaultDocument/files/add[@value="iisstart.htm"]' -Name 'value' -Value (@{value="REMOVE_iisstart.htm"})
```

I used to be able to do this via appcmd: `set config /section:system.webServer/defaultDocument /-files.[value='iisstart.htm']`

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Getting the info back I am using this and it shows nothing as changed when I set a hash table for value=REMOVE_iisstart.htm

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.webServer/defaultDocument/files/add' -Name 'value'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your command just a bit - This command will rename the field

Set-WebConfigurationProperty 'system.webServer/defaultDocument/files/add[@value="iisstart.htm"]' -PSPath 'Machine/WebRoot/AppHost' -Name value -value "Remove_iisstart.htm"

Comment: that's great Sean. Worked perfectly - weird that juggling things around can make a difference! Thanks a lot

Comment: The issue, IMHO, was your filter. This line is closer to what you started  Set-WebConfiguration -Filter system.webServer.defaultDocument -Name files -AtElement @{value="iisstart.htm"} -value @{value="Removeiisstart.htm"} -PSPath 'machine/webroot/apphost

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but i thought i would answer the second piece of this question how to remove the iisstart.htm file entirely with powershell.

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty 'system.webServer/defaultDocument' -Name files.collection -AtElement @{value="iisstart.htm"}
```